# Customed port is not working in Jenkins windows service

Tags: jenkins

I installed Jenkins as a windows service. I could not access the jenkins login page as my other application was running on 8080. So, I changed the port to 8081 in jenkins.xml file where the Jenkins is installed. After changing the port, I restarted the service. When I access the login page, I am getting 404 Not Found error. I changed to some other port, restarted the service. I even restarted the machine to reflect the change. But no help.

Following is the output from Jenkins. It seems that its failed and so its killing the service.

**ERROR:**

```
2016-02-15 14:03:29 - Starting C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jre\bin\java -Xrs -Xmx256m -Dhudson.lifecycle=hudson.lifecycle.WindowsServiceLifecycle -jar "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jenkins.war" --httpPort=8081 --webroot="C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\war"
```

`2016-02-15 14:03:29 - Started 2304
2016-02-15 14:04:31 - Stopping jenkins
2016-02-15 14:04:31 - ProcessKill 2304
2016-02-15 14:04:31 - Send SIGINT 2304
2016-02-15 14:04:31 - SIGINT to 2304 failed - Killing as fallback
2016-02-15 14:04:31 - Send SIGINT 2304
2016-02-15 14:04:31 - SIGINT to 2304 failed - Killing as fallback
2016-02-15 14:04:31 - Finished jenkins`

Please let me know how to fix it to run on the customized port.

**UPDATE**

I forgot to mention that I did netstat in CMD to check on the ports. I am able to see the port, but the state is TIME_WAIT. If I try any port number like 8085 or 8001, anything, I get the TIME_WAIT state.

Whenever I change the port number in jenkins.xml file and restart the service, I get a flashing page with the message "Please wait while Jenkins is getting ready to work" for 2 seconds, and then I get 404 page. I think its purely because of the port.

Comment: Have you checked if the port is open? `netstat` will show you your open ports.

Comment: Are you seeing the 404 error also when you stop the Jenkins service, i.e. is Jenkins failing to start because there's another web service already listening on port 8081?

Comment: @S.Spieker, The particular port is NOT established. Its in TIME_WAIT

Comment: @ChristopherOrr, I dont get the 404 when the service is stopped.  The usual message "This webpage is not available" appears when the service is down. And, No, the port 8081 is not in use. I already checked that. Do I need to add the port in the Firewall settings as well?

Answer (score 1):

I uninstalled the jenkins and then installed again. After shutting the service down, I changed the Port to 8081. Restarted the service and then it worked fine with the new port.

The error might be because of modifying the port without shutting down the service. I dont know why it did not work.

Thanks to all for your help.